# Azure function instance and scaling

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-functions-runtime

By creating Azure function app service under consumption plan with single HTTP trigger function in it, can I control that Azure function app service number of instances serving the incoming request? If yes, how to control app service instance?

If no, what is rationale behind Azure scaling or instantiation logic? If I have singleton static resource like cosmos db connection how it can be shared across the azure function app service instances? to improve performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot determine how the Azure Scale Controller will scale out additional instances of your HTTP-triggered function in the Consumption or Premium plans. The Scale Controller will make its best guess on when additional instances of your function should be provisioned.

Also note that if you went from a cold start to "Everyone on Reddit is requesting my function RIGHT NOW", the Azure Scale Controller is throttled to adding a new instance of your HTTP triggered function to at most one per second. I've run into this one the hard way as the HTTP queue deepens for sudden torrents of traffic.

Also, when your function is scaled out, you have no control in the Consumption and Premium plans on what VM within your region that new instances will be added to. Singleton variables within your Azure Function will only be shared by function instances within the same VM. Plan accordingly. The only way around this behavior is to host your Azure Function on an App Service plan. With this scenario, you KNOW that your Azure Function will be running on the same N VM instances, where N is the number of scaled-out Web App instances.

Comment: @ RobReagan, regardless of App service plan (or) Consumption plan, can a VM host only one instance of Azure function app service? if so, why? because I assume Azure function app services are deployed as a container in a VM & can spin up multiple containers with same image on same VM. In case, a VM can host multi instance of same Azure function app service, will Singleton variables within the AZURE FUNCTION APP SERVICE (not across functions within a function app service) can be shared across its instances hosted in same VM?

Comment: An App Service plan can host more than one instance of an Azure Function. It can also most more than one Azure Function. You can actually have a web app deployed and N different Azure Functions on the same App Service plan. A singleton variable instance can be shared across multiple instances of an Azure Function on the same VM.

Comment: @ RobReagan, Surprised,  to hear out "A singleton variable instance can be shared across multiple instances of an Azure Function on the same VM" and wondering how technically this could be achieved as I'm in assumptions objects of an instance of an application are accessible within the their app domain not outside it for security & various other reasons. Can you refer me to some microsoft documentation so as to refer it to my higher ups when they question me. Thanks.

Comment: I've never seen it in the documentation. But here is an answer to a similar question by Chris Gillum, who is a Principal Software Engineering Manager at Microsoft. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39387423/sharing-an-object-across-several-azure-function-instances. I have seen this behavior myself when needing to scale out and reuse HttpClient or Sql connections.